# Unable to find a matching variant of project :flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I was trying to add flutter module in my existing kotlin based andorid application I follow the manual approach from this blog [Add Flutter to Native Android App](http://lofty-dev.com/flutter-module-native-android/)

but after completing all the steps when I try to launch the app I get this error.[image: build error logs]

The project in which I'm integrating flutter is a multi-module project with multiple buildTypes release,debug,stage.